# jQuery count-- until a specific condition is met

Tags: jquery, count

I have explained in a comment where and what I want the code below to do:

```
$("#run").click(function(){

maxspeed = 1.00;
    if  (maxspeed > 0.07)
        {
            //This is where I want the max speed to countdown at
            //a decrement of -0.01 until it reaches 0.07
        }
    else
        {
            delay(3000);
        }

//Code continues below, I will edit post if required
```

My max speed is already stored in a variable with the value of 0.07. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

[EDIT] Sorry, I should have explained better. I am pretty new to JS/jQuery and I have no idea how to use a count. I want my function to count down until it reaches a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try : `setTimeout()` ?
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should use a TimeInterval and start decreasing maxspeed by 0.07

```
maxspeed -= 0.07;
```

If you use a loop the action will be instant.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var maxspeed = 1.00;
var decrement = 0.01;
counter(maxspeed,decrement);

});

  function counter(maxspeed,decrement)
  {
    while(maxspeed > parseFloat(0.07))
    {
        maxspeed = parseFloat(maxspeed) - parseFloat(decrement);
    alert(maxspeed);
    setTimeout(counter(maxspeed,decrement),3000);
    }       

  }

  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go, will need to make some tweaks to get it to work with my script though.

Comment: Hmm, i've posted a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/62mnS/  

With the alert enabled I can see that it does count down, but I have 2 problems:  

1. It has no affect on the speed of the animation  
2. It gets stuck once 'maxspeed' it reaches 0.7

If you remove the code you've told me to add, you can see what it did originally.